# John The Ripper Unknown ciphertext format name requested

Tags: password-cracking

I wanted to crack my windows xp passwords contained in the SAM file with john the ripper, this file contains hashed passwords with NTLM algorithm, but when i use this command to specify the hashing algorithm `john --format=netntlm password.txt`, i get the following error `Unknown ciphertext format name requested`.

And when i try to crack the password file without the format option, then john the ripper uses the LM algorithm, so this way it will never find the password.

How can i add some new hashing algorithms to john the ripper ??!!

PS : I am using ubuntu 15.10 (with Linux kernel > 4), and i installed john the ripper from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I would guess that the version from the Ubuntu repos isn't the Jumbo edition, which is community supported, and adds a bunch of extra formats. You probably need to grab that version and compile yourself from http://www.openwall.com/john/

Comment: I tried to compile that version but i got a lot of errors (undefined references), where can I get a deb of the the jumbo edition ??!!

Comment: Did you follow the howto at http://openwall.info/wiki/john/tutorials/Ubuntu-build-howto ?

Comment: I had a problem with the last version (1.8), I tried an older one and it worked just fine, thanks bro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "Jumbo" Community supported version of JtR. This has extra hash types and various other optimisations, but may need to be compiled for specific operating systems, such as Ubuntu Linux.

There are some instructions on compiling it at the [JtR wiki](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/tutorials/Ubuntu-build-howto)